# Asp .NET Web Api + MVC + Angular 2 - action with two parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have an ASP .NET MVC application with Angular 2. I added a WebApi Controller and try to communicate from angular service with it, but it does not access an action within the WebApi Controller with two parameters.

I think I read all the question regarding that matter. I have my webApi routes registered before the MVC ones. I can access the action, if it does not require any parameters. But if I try to hit it with the parameters I keep getting 404 not found for the Login action - *POST localhost:12312/api/userapi/login 404 (Not Found).*

**I tried every kind of formatting for the WebApiConfig** - with optional parameters, without them, with dynamic controller placeholders, with the exact names for action and controller,etc. I tried **Routing attribute** as well, but with no effect.

I tried to put it as a **single parameter "object credentials" and modified the WebApiConfig.cs** as well, but the result didn't change.

RouteConfig.cs

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*anything}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 
                     UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
       config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "api",
            routeTemplate: "api/userapi/login/{username}/{password}",
            defaults: new { username = RouteParameter.Optional, password = 
            RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
```

UserApiController.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage LogIn(string username, string password)
    {
        return ToJson(userRep.LogIn(username, password));
    }
```

angular

```
this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(credentials), { headers: headers })
            .subscribe(res => {
                resolve(res.json());
            }, (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure why its not working in your way(using parmas) but i will simply create an model something like

```
public class LoginModel{
    public UserName {get;set;}
    public Password {get;set;}
}
```

then in login mathod

```
 [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage LogIn(LoginModel model)
    {
        return ToJson(userRep.LogIn(model.username, model.password));
    }
```

No need of custom routing just use default config